# Processes & threads C programming on Windows: trouble with command line arguments

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, netbeans, process

I'm working with processes and threads on C language via Netbeans (with Windows 7). 
I'm using command line arguments but when it cames to run the program there's no way it will work. If I use the Run Netbeans button it won't ask for the arguments I need to enter and will display the message:

> /cygdrive/C/Program Files/Netbeans 8.1/ide/bin/nativeexecution/dorun.sh:
>   line 33: 3592 Segmentation Fault (core dumped) sh "${SHFILE}"

I'm trying to use the cmd console but it seems like I'm making something wrong calling the function this way:

> gcc ej1.c 2

I'm supposed to use this format:

> gcc font_file.c -o exe_file.exe

but there's no .exe file on the Netbeans folder as far as I know. Here's the message I get when [running through Windows cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4RkD.png).

And here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    HANDLE hThread2;
    DWORD IDThread2;
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("Parámetro: n = %d\n\n",n);

    printf("Soy el proceso %d\n",(int)GetCurrentProcessId());
    printf("Comienza el hilo primario (ID %d)\n\n",(int)GetCurrentThreadId());


    void func(int *n){
        printf("Comienza el hilo secundario (ID %d)\n",(int)GetCurrentThreadId());
        int i;
        int var = 0;
        for(i=0; i<*n; i++){
            var++;
        }
        printf("Valor final de la variable: %d\n",var);
        printf("Finaliza el hilo secundario (ID %d)\n\n",(int)GetCurrentThreadId());
    }



    hThread2 = CreateThread (NULL,
                            0,
                            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) func,
                            &n,
                            0,
                            &IDThread2);

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread2, // Este es el descriptor dell objeto por el que se espera
                        INFINITE);

    CloseHandle(hThread2);

    printf("Finaliza el hilo primario (ID %d)\n",(int)GetCurrentThreadId());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: besides the problems your having with netbeans, and the way your code is trying to create a thread,  Never access `argv[]` beyond argv[0] until after checking `argc` to assure the parameter actually exists.  Your compiler should be telling you about the unused parameter `argc`.   When `argc` does not contain the correct value, output a `usage` statement to stderr and call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE )`

Answer (score 1):

Function `CreateThread` requires the third parameter to be of type `ThreadProc`, which is a function pointer of type `DWORD(*)(LPVOID)` .

`DWORD` is an unsigned 32 bit integer and `LPVOID` is a pointer to void.

The function your code passes to `CreateThread` has the type `void(*)(int*)`, the types are clearly incompatible.

C Standard states that calling a function through a function pointer that is not compatible with the function type, will result in undefined behavior. This could manifest itself as a segmentation fault.